# Check API REST Salesforce

Tags: community, rest-api

I have a test class of REST API and I want check this.
In workbench it is OK, but now I want check and use with other application. Can I check this class?
I have tried with cURL, but I do not get it; I get an error: {"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}

Thanks

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Account/*')
global with sharing class Test_RestAPI {
    @HttpGet
    global static String getAccountId() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        String toRet = request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        system.debug(toRet);
        system.debug(request.requestURI);
        return '123';
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Juan, are you trying to write an Apex test for this class, or just trying to validate with an API client other than Workbench? If the latter, you need to provide a session id in your headers.

Comment: Hi David. I am trying to validate with an API client. Sorry, not understand "you need to provide a session id in your headers". Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to invoke a REST API exposed from Salesforce from external applications, there are some pre-requisite that needs to be followed. You will need to set the "access token" with your request to be able to call the REST API. Below are the steps those are required:

1. You will need to create a connected app, share the client secret/key to the external system
2. The external system authenticates themselves using OAuth 2.0 and gets the access token
3. Use the access token, set that in the header of the request and then invoke the API

You can follow the steps as outlined in this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm). As an example, how to do this, I have steps outlined in one of [my blog posts](https://jdspaceit.wordpress.com/2016/09/26/using-postman-for-testing-salesforce-rest-apis/) using POSTMAN, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a Salesforce Apex REST endpoint requires an authenticated session, except in the case that the endpoint is exposed via a public Force.com Site.

When you test in Workbench, you're already authenticated to Salesforce, and Workbench provides the required authentication header. If you're not using Workbench, you'll need to handle authentication yourself, extract the Session Id, and provide it in an `Authorization: Bearer <session id here>` header.

There's a good example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm) in the Salesforce REST API documentation. The authentication process doesn't differ here because you're using a custom REST endpoint.  You execute the Username-Password OAuth flow in CURL, after setting up a Connected App :

> curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=myclientid" -d "client_secret=myclientsecret" 
>       -d "username=mylogin@salesforce.com" -d "password=mypassword123456"

(Note that in a sandbox you'd be using `test.salesforce.com`).

That'll net you a session Id you can provide to `curl` with `-H`:

> curl https://instance_name.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account -H 'Authorization: Bearer access_token'